# Define a method that works on arrays of a specific type of object

Tags: ruby, extension-methods

In C# you can write an extension method like this:

```
public static Debt[] Foo(this Debt[] arr, int num)
{
    // Do something
}
```

This would allow you to use `Foo()` on an array of debts: `debts.Foo(3)`

Can you do this in Ruby? I know you can write a method that will work on arrays:

```
class Array
  def foo
    # blah
  end
end
```

but this works on all types of arrays, not just an array of `Debt`s

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `extend` method is adding the instance methods to a particular object. so in you case it would be:

```
class YourClass
  def foo
    # blah
  end
end

debts.extend(YourClass)
debts.foo # now foo method is instance method of debts object
```

Actually it creates singleton class for `debts` object and then add to it the method. But you can't use this class, that's why it called "ghost" class

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but where would I call `debts.extend` in my program? I am using rails.

Comment: you mean is there special place like for helpers? I don't know, but extend in Rails usually using for quiet mixing                    def self.included(base)
   base.extend ClassMethods
end It's a metaprogramming, look at this http://pragprog.com/screencasts/v-dtrubyom/the-ruby-object-model-and-metaprogramming

Answer (score 1):

This would be a little tricky because Ruby arrays are not homogeneous. That is, you can store different types of objects inside of an array. That would lead me to a solution where I need to first verify that all objects in the array are of type `Debt`, and if they are then I can act on the array using `foo`.

You can continue to open up `Array` and add the `foo` method, but maybe you should create a `FooArray` instead and extend `Array`. This way you can redefine some methods such as `<<` and `push` to ensure you only take `Debt`s. Since you know that only `Debt`s can be added to your array, you could call `foo()` without worry.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this by extending Ruby's Array class or better yet defining your own Array-like class and delegating the selected array methods to the native object.

```
Stack = Array.extract([
  :last,
  :push,
  :pop,
  :size,
  :clear,
  :inspect,
  :to_s
])
```

Why this is better than the alternative methods is [explained here](http://rubylution.ping.de/articles/2005/12/21/rubys-rich-array-api).